What does Homer mean by "Canada's answer to E.L.P."?
In The Simpsons episode, Saddlesore Galactica (Season 11, Episode 13), Homer is introducing Bart to the music of Bachman–Turner Overdrive:

That's B.T.O. They were Canada's answer to E.L.P. Their biggest hit was T.C.B. That was how we talked in the seventies. We didn't have a moment to spare.

What does "ELP" or "E.L.P." refer to in this context?
You can view the clip here.

ELP is Emerson, Lake & Palmer.

Emerson, Lake & Palmer (informally known as ELP) were an English progressive rock supergroup formed in London in 1970.

TCB is Takin' Care of Business






Ahhhhh - as a Canadian who grew up listening to BTO - I knew what TCB was :) - but I'd never heard of Emerson, Lake & Palmer before. Thanks!

@Tronman “Karn Evil 9” is pretty great. I don’t know anything else by them but that one’s worth a listen.

I know it doesn’t work with the joke, but I would argue that Homer is just dead wrong here – BTO’s biggest hit is not TCB, but YASNY (aka You Ain’t Seen Nothing Yet. Personally, I’d never heard TCB before playing the embedded YouTube video here just now.

@JanusBahsJacquet While YASNY reached higher on the charts (it's their only #1 single), Wikipedia refers to TCB as "one of BTO's most enduring and well-known songs". So it's not really a stretch to call it their biggest hit, and I think you're unusual in never having heard it before.

@Barmar I wonder if there might be a bit of an American-European divide here, where YASNY was a big hit in both America and Europe, while TCB was only a hit in America. TCB is also special in that it's been so heavily used in movies and TV shows. I know YASNY very well as a normal song and could sing along to most of the lyrics, while I know TCB as a single catchy line that pops up every once in a while in an American movie to illustrate that the protagonist is executing a plan or something.

TCB also gets used in a lot of commercials.
